# JSP page construction through database fields

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, jsp

I would like to develop an application which is capable of adding fields dynamically to a page. For example,

"Student module" will have fields like name, email, mobile and DOB, etc. To create the student record user must fill all the fields. This is fine for customer 1. But for customer 2 want to have other fields like gender, father and mother which is not required for the customer 1.

They are two different customers, say customer 1 is managing schools and customer 2 is managing colleges, hence their business is different.

To address the customer 2 requirement, it would be ideal to provide ability to add fields dynamically on page as per the customers. May be through seed data for page fields that constructs the page dynamically.

**Precise Question :**

In Module, Ability to construct the page dynamically with the fields from database. Typically fields are name, email, mobile, dob, parent's mobile and address. Upon submission, respective values should be stored into the respective database columns.

Currently we are using `spring`, `struts` and `hibernate` technologies for the application. I think to support this requirement existing frameworks may not work and need to develop framework or any other existing framework that supports this requirement?

Could you please provide any suggestion or links to accomplish this task.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inherited entities from Hibernate.

There are three types of inheritance mapping in hibernate

```
1. Table per concrete class with unions 
2. Table per class hierarchy(Single Table Strategy) 
3. Table per subclass
```

So you can define one base Entity - let's name it BaseStudent and 2 classes extening Customer1Student and Customer2Student.

For DB I would choose one table (to be simpler) for both classes. The table will contain all the columns for the fields of both students.

A good example is [here](http://www.dineshonjava.com/p/implementing-inheritance-in-hibernate.html#.VoTiGPl95aQ)

Comment: Thanks for taking time to post. My requirement is ability add fileds without change the code, everthing should be drive from database scripts. Lets say customer need one more column like hallticket then ability add the that column without changing the code. Hope you understand the requirement.

Answer (score -1):

Yes we can use inheritance mapping.. but mostly suitable thing is Table Per Susclass.

here we dont' need of super class. we just need sub class only which are says Customer1 and customer2 classes.

we can insert the data in different tables for cust1 and cust2.. as well as fetch data is separately. then create the UI also different for both..

comming to the data base here total 3 tables are created.

1 is for super class, remaining two are for subclasses separately which is we want to get dynamic whatever you want.

Thanking you..